# Step 2 on the Meteor tutorial trips me up

Tags: javascript, meteor

I would guess this is a simple one, but being new, it's got me.

I've created the simple-todos app and it runs fine, displaying on localhost:3000.  As soon as I update the html and JS in step 2 of the tutorial and run it I get:

---

Errors prevented startup:

While processing files with templating (for target web.browser):
simple-todos.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)

Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.

---

I'm on a mac using textedit.  See here: https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/templates

Comment: can you paste your simple-todo.html code?

Comment: It would be helpful if you pasted the template code here. But it might be that you've included `doctype` in your template when meteor does that for you

Comment: Here is the code they suggest:  

<head>
 
  <title>Todo List</title>

</head>

 

<body>

  <div class="container">

    <header>

      <h1>Todo List</h1>

    </header>

 

    <ul>

      {{#each tasks}}

        {{> task}}

      {{/each}}

    </ul>

  </div>

</body>

 

<template name="task">

  <li>{{text}}</li>

</template>

Comment: For a better view of the html, you can see it here: https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/templates

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a tag like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Delete this and  tags if you have.

If you give us a pastebin-link with your simple-todos.html, we will see the error.But Meteor tells you, the error is in the 1st line in simple-todos.html

Comment: It wasn't there.  I was using textedit as my editor and someone that was causing problems, even though everything looked exactly like it was supposed to.  So now I'm using Atom.  If you have an editor suggest for Meteor other than that, please let me know.

Comment: Paste your html file. Without your code we are "just talking"